# Getting key names in EF 4.4.0 (without 'ObjectContext')

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can I get key names in EF 4.4?

I found a sample like this:

```
var set = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
var entitySet = set.EntitySet;
return entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);
```

I get this when run the website:
CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I use .NET 4 and below is my web.config:

```
    <section name="entityFramework" 
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
      EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

I spent one day but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why isn't this valid? It should be. Do you get a compiler error or a runtime exception or a wrong result?

Comment: I've added the error. In References, when I click on EntityFramework, it shows 'Version: 4.4.0.0'

Comment: I believe you need to update the config (web.config or app.config) file to have the proper reference in the `configSections` element
(specifically the `<section name="entityFramework" ... />` key

Comment: "*You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity...*" says the exception. It is in the solution explorer under your project -> Node "References" -> right mouse click -> Add reference

Comment: I think the error message and the actual error are unrelated in this case. I remember reading that EF 4.4 is something of a config nightmare, and have since decided to use EF 4 with .Net 4, or EF 5 with .Net 4.5.

Comment: You're right Christopher; Actually, I installed EF 5 from NuGet Package Manager, but because of using .NET 4 in my project, it was downgraded to EF 4.4. As you said, EF 5 features are only possible in .NET 4.5

Comment: @Slauma: I added my web.config setting to the question. I don't wanna change the EF 4.4.0.0 to EF 4.0.0.0.

Comment: It isn't a downgrade when you add the `System.Data.Entity.dll` assembly to the project references. EF 4.4 is built on top of EF 4.0 anyway and you need that assembly in order to have access to the `ObjectContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it by reinstalling EF. I used NUGET Package Manger and uninstalled EF and again added EF 5.